# Find the solution to the differential equation

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, logarithms, differential

Assume $x\gt 0$ and let

$$x(x+1)\frac{du}{dx} = u^2,$$
$$u(1) = 4.$$

I started off by doing some algebra to get:

$$\frac{1}{u^2}du = \frac{1}{x^2+x}dx.$$

I then took the partial fraction of the right side of the equation:

$$\frac{1}{u^2}du = \left(\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{x+1}\right).$$

I then took the integral of both sides:

$$-\frac{1}{u} = \log{x}-\log{(x+1)}+C.$$

From here I don't know what to do because we are solving for $u(x)$ and I'm not sure how to get that from $-\frac{1}{u}$.

Comment: -1/u=ln(x)-ln(x+1)+C hense u=-1/(ln(x)-ln(x+1)+C)

Comment: so, just multiply through the equation by a negative, and then take the reciprocal of both sides..

Comment: Before doing what @izoec recommends you can determine $C=-\frac{1}{u(1)}+\log{2}$

Comment: @marwalix is correct - as you have an initial condition, you must specify the value $C$. In general, it is easier to do this now before solving for $u$ as a function of $x$, rather then solving for $u$ and then deducing the value of $C$ from a more complicated equation.

Comment: It's a little embarrassing how simple of a fix that was, thanks for the answers though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solving for $\frac{du}{dx}$ we have

\begin{equation*}
\frac{du}{dx}=\frac{u^2}{x(x+1)}\\
\Rightarrow \frac{du}{dx}=\frac{u^2}{x^2+x}\\
\frac{\frac{du}{dx}}{u^2}=\frac{1}{x^2+x}.
\end{equation*}

Integrate both sides & evaluate the integrals:

\begin{equation*}
-\frac{1}{u}=\log(x)-\log(x+1)+C_1\\
\Rightarrow u=-\frac{1}{\log(x)-\log(x+1)+C_1}.
\end{equation*}

Now apply the initial condition:

\begin{equation*}
-\frac{1}{C_1-\log(2)}=4\Rightarrow C_1=\frac{1}{4}(-1+4\log(2)).
\end{equation*}

This gives the result.